# http client for restful webservice gets SSL handshake exception

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httpclient, restful-authentication

I get SSL Handshake exception from my Java code

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.mkyong.rest.client.NetClientGet.main(NetClientGet.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
```

My Java file

```
package com.mypackage.rest.client;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ClientGet {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(
                "https://sandbox.tangocard.com/raas/v1.1/orders/116-101338692-28");         
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Platform_Name", "CareHeroTest");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Platform_key","8heOCfIEJHgarCraHuvqQ6vcajgu8A1r7YU4jUFLjxNtwbuREfBuO54E");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic VGFuZ29UZXN0OjV4SXRyM2RNRGxFV0FhOVM0czd2WWg3a1EwMWQ1U0ZlUFBVb1paaUsvdk1mYm8zQTVCdkpMQW1ENHRJPQ==");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The same third party web service (Tango) works when retrieve order_id information using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

This means the end service is working fine with the authorization I provide.

[image]

Platform_Name - `CareHeroTest`

Platform_key - `8heOCfIEJHgarCraHuvqQ6vcajgu8A1r7YU4jUFLjxNtwbuREfBuO54E`

Authorization - `Basic VGFuZ29UZXN0OjV4SXRyM2RNRGxFV0FhOVM0czd2WWg3a1EwMWQ1U0ZlUFBVb1paaUsvdk1mYm8zQTVCdkpMQW1ENHRJPQ==`

What am I doing wrong? As there is no other handshake or certificate given by Tango.

Comment: Did you import the SSL certificate into java keytool?

Comment: There is no SSL needed I suppose. This should be basic HTTP transaction, with basic access authentication. I guess I need to perform `Base64 encoding`

Comment: This is an SSL exception, not `403 Not Authorized` HTTP status. This means your request is never transmitted to the server. With the Postman example you clearly use `https://`, which involves an SSL handshake. The latter fails as you probably do not have the certificate imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) API and it worked.

```
package com.ansari.examples.javahttpapiclient;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;

public class JavaHTTPAPIClient {
public void getQuestionsUsingUnirest() throws Exception {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://sandbox.tangocard.com/raas/v1.1/orders/116-101338692-28").
            header("accept",  "application/json").
            header("Authorization", "Basic VGFuZ29UZXN0OjV4SXRyM2RNRGxFV0FhOVM0czd2WWg3a1EwMWQ1U0ZlUFBVb1paaUsvdk1mYm8zQTVCdkpMQW1ENHRJPQ==").
            asJson();
    System.out.println(response.getBody().getObject().toString(2));
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JavaHTTPAPIClient client = new JavaHTTPAPIClient();
    client.getQuestionsUsingUnirest();
}
}
```